# dnsmasq ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I created ubuntu 22.04 router for my home network with dnsmasq and everytime i do a google search and landed on a website that is sponsored by google, it will result ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I'm not sure what's wrong with my config for dnsmasq, but this is the following configs:

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
port=53
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dnssec
strict-order
listen-address=172.16.0.1,172.16.1.1
expand-hosts
dhcp-range=enp3s0,172.16.0.100,172.16.0.200,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-range=enp4s0,172.16.1.100,172.16.1.200,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,172.16.0.1
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,172.16.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,172.16.0.1
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.255.0

dhcp-host=b0:a7:b9:fb:c5:00, iptime, 172.16.0.100, infinite
dhcp-host=b0:a7:b9:fb:c5:01, iptime, 172.16.0.101, infinite
dhcp-host=a8:a1:59:ea:a3:44, iptime,172.16.1.2, infinite
dhcp-host=98:dd:60:02:13:b3, iptime, 172.16.0.3, infinite
dhcp-host=40:16:7e:34:ef:9c, iptime, 172.16.0.4, infinite
dhcp-host=56:c0:c5:55:eb:00, iptime, 172.16.0.5, infinite
dhcp-host=36:be:69:f8:ae:44, iptime, 172.16.0.6, infinite
dhcp-host=60:06:e3:1d:f8:c9, iptime, 172.16.0.7, infinite
dhcp-host=44:a8:fc:bb:88:81, iptime, 172.16.0.8, infinite
dhcp-authoritative
cache-size=10000
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

172.16.0.1  server.local
172.16.0.1  transmission.server.local
172.16.0.1  cockpit.server.local
172.16.0.1  syncthing.server.local
172.16.0.1  nvr.server.local
172.16.0.1  nvr-archive.server.local
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.0.1/24
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.1/24
```

Comment: For the purpose of troubleshooting does the problem still occur if you disable dnssec and strict-order?

Comment: @thomasrutter hi, thx for the response. yes it's still occuring, any other idea?

Comment: I can't test this out right now, but it appears that if you are going to use the `172.16.0.x` IP range you can't use it as a `/24` network but it would have to be a `/12`.  You might want to pick a different IP address range if you want to use different subnets like that.  See:  https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/

Comment: I don't have other ideas sorry, it's strange to me that dns would cause that, good luck

Comment: wow... that 172 ip address is peculiar, i will try to configure to 192 later and tell you if it solves

Comment: no problem @thomasrutter, any idea is worth a try anyway

Comment: @Terrance not working either haha

Comment: While it is supposed to be allowed to use the `172.16.x.x` IP address range as a private IP, I do tend to stay away from that one to avoid possible sites blocking me.  But, after I sent you that message I realized that changing the IP address wouldn't change anything as the issue is probably lying in the DNS.  There are so many things to try for that error.  You many want to look at https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/